# UISlider thumbImage for a disabled slider

Tags: ios, objective-c, uislider

I'm trying to create a UISlider with a custom thumb image.  This works fine, but does not work if I disable the slider.  Here's my code:

```
UISlider *slider = [[UISlider alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(130, 10, sliderBG.size.width, sliderBG.size.height)];
slider.enabled = NO;
[slider setThumbImage:thumbCircle forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
```

2 questions:

1) It's using the right image when I set state for UIControlStateHighlighted, but not when I set state to UIControlStateDisabled.  Why?

2) The thumb image looks transparent.  My image is not transparent.  Is the UISlider doing this?  Any way to get around it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is how `UISlider` work: use a transparent knob to indicate inactivity. If you want one that does not do that, try recreate it yourself using several UIImageView's and following a finger isn't that difficult on iOS.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding:

```
[slider setThumbImage:thumbCircle forState: UIControlStateDisabled ];
```